# Where in the world can you see WWII U-boats or U-boat pens?

Tags: germany, history, military, submarines

Where in the world can you still see German WWII U-boats or U-boat pens?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Preserved U-boats [1]:

#### 1) Maritime Museum, Bremerhaven, Bremen, Germany

- **U-2540 / Wilhelm Bauer**, Type XXI [scuttled near Flensburg 1945, salvaged 1957, relaunched 1960 as 'Wilhelm Bauer', became museum ship 1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_submarine_Wilhelm_Bauer)

#### 2) [Laboe Naval Museum, near Kiel, Schlweswig-Holstein, Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laboe_Naval_Memorial)

- **U-995**, type VII-C/41 [surrendered 1945 to British at Trondheim, Norway, 1952-1965 became Norwegian submarine Kaura, became museum ship at Laboe 1971](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_submarine_U-995)
- [Laboe Naval Memorial (Marine-Ehrenmal) - Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g187412-d1045351-Reviews-Laboe_Naval_Memorial_Marine_Ehrenmal-Kiel_Schleswig_Holstein.html)
- thanks to @CarlChristian for posting it [in this question about Kiel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/171680/how-to-spend-1900-to-100-in-kiel-from-ferry-to-train)

#### 3) [Birkenhead, Merseyside, UK](https://www.visitliverpool.com/things-to-do/u-boat-story-p229341)

- **U-534** Type IXC/40 [sunk by RAF bomber 1945 in the Kattegat (Denmark),
  salvaged in 1993 by a Danish team, brought to Birkenhead in 1996, museum since 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_submarine_U-534)

#### 4) Museum of Science and Industry, Chicago, Illinois, USA

- **U-505**, Type IXC [captured by US Navy, June 4, 1944, renovated and became museum ship in 1954, moved to indoor exhibition hall 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_submarine_U-505)

#### 5) [Finnish submarine Vesikko, Helsinki, Finland](https://www.suomenlinna.fi/en/visitor/museums/vesikko/)

- Type CV-707. Technically [originally built for Germany (1933), but operated by Finland 1937-44, not scrapped 1945 unlike the rest of the fleet, renovated as museum piece 1973](https://sotamuseo.fi/en/submarine-vesikko)

#### U-boat bases:

- The five bases in occupied France were [Lorient](https://www.historynet.com/frances-u-boat-bunkers-survived-the-war-and-thrive-today.htm), Brest, Saint-Nazaire, La Pallice(/La Rochelle), and Bordeaux. Some parts of those pens remain.

Sources:

[1]: [AtlasObscura "Remains of the U-Boats’ Watery Reign: The Four Final Iron Coffins", a list of preserved U-boats](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/remains-of-the-uboats-watery-reign-the-four-final-iron-coffins)

- Drawing of all WW2 German Submarine Types(1933-45):
  https://naval-encyclopedia.com/ww2/germany/u-boats-german-submarines

Comment: Last time I went to the sub pens at Bordeaux (Nov 2021) they had [an astonishing son-et-lumiere](https://uk.france.fr/en/happening-now-in-france/klime-klee-bassins-de-lumieres-bordeaux) installation that projected huge Klimt images onto the walls, while playing Wagner (and other composers) through enormous speaker systems.  Wonderful experience, and more to your point, those pens are definitely still open.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dora_II

Comment: There is a *prototype* of the Type II class on display at on the fortress island of Suomenlinna just outside Helsinki, Finland https://www.suomenlinna.fi/en/visitor/museums/vesikko/
This is a list of surviving midget submarines 
https://uboat.net/fates/midget.htm
I can add that there is also a Marder one-man torpedo at the Marine Museum in Aalborg, Denmark,
https://springeren-maritimt.dk/en/
I have not been there in many years, but online photos suggest that it is still there.
There is a U-boat assembly hall at Gdansk, Poland. I can't speak for the experience.

Comment: Google Maps marks UBoat Story in the UK as temporarily closed. The linked website says it's open though, so probably best to call ahead.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentin_submarine_pens might also be of interest, somewhat close to the Sub in Bremerhaven (< 50 miles). See https://www.denkort-bunker-valentin.de/index.php?id=108

Comment: "Some parts of those pens remain." My understanding was that they couldn't be destroyed. At least, not without destroying the whole city around it. So they're here for all eternity, and get converted to museums, concert halls, bars, ...

Comment: @EricDuminil: they're not concert halls or bars, certainly not in France. People wouldn't celebrate that.

Comment: @smci "certainly not in France". Right. Here's an [example](https://www.lorientbretagnesudtourisme.fr/fr/fiche/hydrophone-lorient_TFOZHYDROPHONE) in Lorient.

Comment: @EricDuminil: ok, I'm totally wrong then. I visited Saint-Nazaire, Lorient and Vannes; Finistere certainly weren't having a party at their WWII monument to sailors. Didn't realize the former Saint-Nazaire U-boat pens still exist and were now a cafe and bar. (We had tried to find out at the monument where the pens were and if they still existed, but nobody could tell us. So much for tourism.)

Comment: @smci: events there are not meant as a sign of disrespect towards fallen soldiers/sailors/civilians. Since the buildings will probably always be there, the locals might as well use them to celebrate life. It took a few generations after WW2, though. What is there to see in Vannes?

Comment: @EricDuminil: [Vannes is a superbly preserved medieval walled city](https://www.brittanytourism.com/destinations/the-10-destinations/southern-brittany-morbihan-gulf/vannes/); also had a couple of Roman sites.

Comment: @smci: Sorry, my question wasn't specific enough. I meant: what is there to see in Vannes, related to WW2 / U-Boats?

Comment: @EricDuminil: nothing in Vannes, unlike Saint-Nazaire and Lorient; I'm simply saying I visited three major historical places in Brittany and none of the tourist literature said a word about WW2 U-boats, let alone where to see the former U-Boat pens. It was all about waterparks and suchlike. So I never got to see them, despite trying (I did see the WW2 memorial at Finistère). Hence the motivation for this question. I take it the French aren't proud about the German occupation using their ports as U-boat bases.